# Expose (OSX Style) Functionality in Unity

Tags: unity

Does anyone know if there is a ***application window*** expose (a la Mac OSX) for the Unity Desktop. I've used the Compiz Expose Plugin, but that performs an "expose" on workspaces. I'm looking for something which will show me all of the active windows and allow me to select one.

I know this functionality is included in the launder bar, but frankly - this is bogus. I don't want to search for little tick marks, I want a representation of all of the open windows in the application area of Unity.

This simply cannot ***not*** exist in a "unified" window environment such as OSX / Unity.

Comment: It might be worth noting that this does currently not work in Ubuntu 12.04 due to [a bug in Compiz.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/933776) I think a fix is in the works, but until then don't expect it to work well. It should however work for some of the earlier versions of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 59):

<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> should automatically be set in 11.04 (<kbd>Super</kbd> is the Windows key on most keyboards). If that doesn't work, look into the CompizConfig Settings Manager ([install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager)) and search for "Scale" to change various settings.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 8):

Scale plugin. All settings are here -

CCSM > Window Management > Scale

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

if you don't have it already

Comment: This can be used to assign "mouse to the top left corner" gesture to the action. run `ccsm` -> Window Management -> Scale -> Bindings -> Initiate Window Picker -> select corner.